# Configuring Cloud Run services and GCS Buckets with a load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I would like to setup a HTTPS load balancer to serve both static content from a storage bucket and also point to a number of cloud run services.

The setup I am trying to achieve looks like the following:

```
// prod
api.example.com/serviceA -> cloud run: serviceA
api.example.com/serviceB -> cloud run: serviceB
cdn.example.com/cat.jpg -> storage bucket: cats

// dev
api-dev.example.com/serviceA -> cloud run: serviceA
api-dev.example.com/serviceB -> cloud run: serviceB
cdn-dev.example.com/cat.jpg -> storage bucket: cats-dev
```

The dev & prod environments are separated by projects in my case.

I have followed this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) as to how to setup this configuration.

However I am unable to resolved the various services. It is not 100% clear how the following elements interact:

- url map
- url mask
- custom domain mapping in cloud run itself VS at the load balancer level

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it can be confusing!

- URL Map: it's plugged on the Load Balancer to route a URL to a backend (Bucket, (un)Managed instance group (MIG), Network Endpoint Group (NEG)). For example the /static/ is routed to a bucket, the others to a serverless NEG
- URL Mask: it's plugged on the serverless NEG. You can define a template on the URL Name to extract the service name (and tag) from the URL itself. It requires to have a dependency between your site structure and your Cloud Run service naming.

**Summary**

The URL Map is the first pass routing to the serverless NEG. The serverless NEG apply the URL mask to route the request to the correct service.

**Custom domain mapping**

On a single Cloud Run service you can apply a custom domain to reach it directly. In this case, you have no load balancing, you reach directly only one service deployed on Cloud Run.

I hope to be clear!!

Comment: Thanks @guillaume so when using A record pointing to the LB, do I need to still add custom domain mapping to cloud run?

Comment: No, you don't need a custom domain if you use the load balancer. The URL Map then the NEG route the request to your service. The custom domain mapping is useful to reach directly the Cloud Run service.

Comment: @dendog, please mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue, otherwise, please update your answer.

Comment: @Juancki no this answer did not actually explain how one would set this up.

Comment: @dendog I tried to clarify that was unclear for you. If it's now clearer for you, can you update your question and detail your blocking points. We will be able to help you more on what you want to achieve!